# Sharepoint list does not exist on the site efter but it exists in my code when debugging

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I shall eventually create a sharepoint calendar. I want to create a eventslist here but I'll get this strange error here.

I create a a eventslist and then check [to see] if its already created. If it is, not I want to create it but then my testLabel says that its already exists.

When I try to delete the list, on the `myButton_Click`, it gives me this error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: List 'CompanyCalendar'
>   does not exist at site with URL 'http://server1'.

**Code**

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace CalendarWeb.Pages
{
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Uri hostWeb = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);

        using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            ListCreationInformation listCreator = new ListCreationInformation();
            listCreator.Title = "CompanyCalendar";
            listCreator.Description = "Workcalendar";

            listCreator.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.Events;
            var ifListExcists = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listCreator.Title);
            if (ifListExcists == null)
            {
                web.Lists.Add(listCreator);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                testLabel.Text = "The " + listCreator.Title + " list was created";
            }
            else
            {
                testLabel.Text = "List already excist";
            }
        }
    }

    protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri hostWeb = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;

            var deleteList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("CompanyCalendar");
            deleteList.DeleteObject();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            testLabel.Text = "list deleted";
        }

    }
}
}
```

When I look at my server1 site the list is not there but in the code it seems like its there since my variable `"ifListExcists"` is never null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ifListExists`  variable would never be null because its not executed on server.

Use following method to check if list exists or not:

```
private bool ValdiateList(ClientContext clientContext, string listName, out List existingList)    
{

    Web web = clientContext.Web;

    existingList =null;

    ListCollection lists = web.Lists;

    var existingLists 
                  = clientContext.LoadQuery(lists.Where(list => list.Title == listName));

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    existingList = existingLists.FirstOrDefault();

    return (existingList != null);

}
```

Comment: It works now! What I did in addition to your answear was that I deleted the line "var ifListExcists = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listCreator.Title);" in page load and in the Validation method I changed "IEnumerable" to "IEnumerable<List>". Problem solved. Thanks alot!

Comment: You could modify the ending code to be `return existingLists.Any()` since you are not using the return value of `FirstOrDefault`.